# Table row not updating

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Problem is that if I update all users at one time the points row updates. But if I updating it by username row wont updating. I don't know why.

```
foreach($points as $p) {
  $p = $p['points'] - $bet;
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $q = $pdo -> prepare("UPDATE users SET points = '$p', username = '$username' ");
  $q->execute();
}
```

without `'username = $username'` all users updates perfectly.

Comment: Note that you are updating all the rows in `users`.

Comment: Seems like you've probably an unset variable somewhere. Here, add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, since you're probably not checking for errors. Plus, is `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: Yes, session is started.

Comment: As Ende Neu pointed out, you are updating all rows since there is no `WHERE` clause. All values will bet set to the value in the last iteration through the foreach loop. Also, you must either use `bindParam()` to bind the variables or pass the variables in `execute()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
try {
    $q = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET points = ? WHERE username = ?");
    $q->execute(array($p, $username));
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Or:

```
try {
    $q = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET points = :p WHERE username = :username");
    $q->bindParam(':p', $p);
    $q->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $q->execute();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

I haven't tested it, but I think that should work.

Check out the [site.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: wrap your code in a try { } catch block and it will spit out what may be happening.

Comment: Have you tried just hard coding what you think the SQL is one time? I.E. "UPDATE users SET points = 200 WHERE username = 'username'"
Also, try trimming $_SESSION['username']; perhaps there are extra spaces.

Comment: There was no error in try catch block. But now everything is working with second code! Thank you!!

Comment: In your second example, don't forget to use `bindParam()`.

Comment: This `WHERE username = ':username'");` is incorrect. `WHERE username = :username");` Remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE username = 'username' or else with that lack of code, all rows are getting updated and that could be either planned or disaster.

Comment: var_dump($p);
after submit button I got this:
array(2) { ["points"]=> string(3) "300" [0]=> string(3) "300" } array(2) { ["points"]=> string(3) "400" [0]=> string(3) "400" }

Comment: add ticks on '$p' and run it just to make sure someone didn't varchar the field. I'm not saying this will work, I'm saying this is a good time to see.

Answer (score -1):

As `points` is an integer, you should **NOT** use quotes around the variable, as it will be interpreted as a string, thus failing. So the correct syntax would be:

```
"UPDATE users SET points = {$p}, username = '{$username}'"
```

Comment: I did not downvote btw, but I think PDO takes care of that, whether they're quoted or not.

Comment: I was too quick there, as I didn't notice that he was using PDO. Thomas Powers's answer is of course the correct one in this case.

Comment: PDO or not, MySQL does the conversion.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Not if mysql has `strict_mode` enabled, which is recommended to keep a more sane and consistent code. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: Even with "strict mode", MySQL still converts from string to integer and vice versa without complaint.